# objective c, nsstring to nsarray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Im new to objective C so I need some help, is there any fast way of converting this string:
`{{2, 2}, {103, 166}}` to an `NSArray`, or just getting out the values to four `NSInteger`?

Comment: How did you get this string? Is it json or something?

Comment: I got it from a .plist file where the value was a string who looked like that. I got the file from Zwoptex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the storage format of a `CGRect`/`NSRect`. You can easily read it using `CGRectFromString`/`NSRectFromString` and then get the values like this:

```
NSString *string = @"{{2, 2}, {103, 166}}";
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(string);
CGFloat x = rect.origin.x; // 2
CGFloat y = rect.origin.y; // 2
CGFloat width = rect.size.width; // 103
CGFloat height = rect.size.height; // 166
```